glossaries + \href{#link} is not working
The following code does not seem to work when the command \href{} is used. If it is commented out, it works just fine. Any idea on how to fix the issue?
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makenoidxglossaries
\longnewglossaryentry{sample}
{
    name={sample},
    description = {%
            \item ``\lipsum[1]'' \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstructurecite#_note-1}{wikipedia}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall
    \printnoidxglossary[nonumberlist]
\end{document}

The following error message is given:
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@glo@desc.
<to be read again> 
c
l.19
   
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

The issue is with the "#" character in the \href link. But the error is related to the glossaries package. In other words, if i use \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstructure#cite_note-1} outside the glossary entry definition the code runs just fine.
Thank you very much for your time!

Escape the hash: \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstructurecite\#_note-1}

It works, thank you so much!
